# Call to WCF WebService works locally but not from Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, wcf, azure-web-app-service

I have a WCF WebService (.NET 4.0) that is accessible through a public IP address. I have a C# MVC project running (.NET 4.7.2) that I host in Azure. I connect to this WCF Service as a Connected Service in my VS2017 project.

[image]

[image]

When I run the MVC app locally it works fine - I can connect to the service and read the data. However, when I publish to the Azure AppService I get an error:

> There was no endpoint listening at
> http://12.3.456.78:8080/MyService.svc that could accept the
> message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
> See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> InnerException:
> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
> because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed because connected host has
> failed to respond 12.3.456.78:8080

It isn't a firewall issue - the firewall on the server that hosts the WCF service doesn't register any requests. It's like Azure just won't fire the request.

My code is very simple:

```
using (var service = new MyService.ServiceClient())
{
   List<MyObject> res = service.GetMyStuff(); // This throws the error
}
```

Comment: Is the actual IP address you're using the _external_ IP address? Is port 8080 forwarded? Can you connect to it from for instance Postman?

Comment: Yeah, the IP is an external, public IP that I can access from anywhere.. just not my Azure App Service for some reason.

Comment: Can you ping the IP from the Kudu console?

Comment: No - I cannot ping anything from Kudu, actually. I get: "ping google.com
Unable to contact IP driver. General failure"